# How to convert numerical values to a categorical variable using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

pyspark dataframe which have a range of numerical variables.

for eg

my dataframe have a column value from 1 to 100.

1-10  - group1<== the column value for 1 to 10 should contain group1 as value
11-20 - group2
.
.
.
91-100 group10

how can i achieve this using pyspark dataframe

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please give us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) and show us your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Creating an arbitrary DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,54),(2,7),(3,72),(4,99)], ['ID','Var'])
df.show()
+---+---+
| ID|Var|
+---+---+
|  1| 54|
|  2|  7|
|  3| 72|
|  4| 99|
+---+---+
```

Once the `DataFrame` has been created, we use [`floor()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.floor) function to find the integral part of a number. For eg; `floor(15.5)` will be `15`. We need to find the integral part of the `Var/10` and add 1 to it, because the indexing starts from 1, as opposed to 0. Finally, we have need to prepend `group` to the value. Concatenation can be achieved with [`concat()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) function, but keep in mind that since the prepended word `group` is not a column, so we need to put it inside [`lit()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit) which creates a column of a literal value.

```
# Requisite packages needed
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, floor, lit, concat
df = df.withColumn('Var',concat(lit('group'),(1+floor(col('Var')/10))))
df.show()
+---+-------+
| ID|    Var|
+---+-------+
|  1| group6|
|  2| group1|
|  3| group8|
|  4|group10|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: You can also replace 1+floor with ceil function, anyways please mark it as answered if this solved your problem

Comment: @sramalingam24 haha, in haste I almost forgot. Thanks for the remark :)